# How can I invoke a class method by NSInvocation?

Tags: objective-c

We can get `NSMethodSignature` by `+ (NSMethodSignature *)instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector` of `NSObject`. Then construct `NSInvocation` by `+ (NSInvocation *)invocationWithMethodSignature:(NSMethodSignature *)signature`

Here is the problem. We can only get the method signature of *instance*，how about the class method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the class methods by:

```
NSMethodSignature *pMS = [[YourObject class] methodSignatureForSelector: (SEL)aSelector];
```

The fragment `[YourObject class]` returns an instance of the class object (singleton) which you can then use to get class methods.

**ADD:** New info from comments below.  You can just do the following:

```
NSMethodSignature *pMS = [YourObject methodSignatureForSelector: (SEL)aSelector];
```

Comment: You don't even need the `class` part. You can just send it to `YourObject`, and it will still work, as class names are also first-class objects as well as being typedefs.

Comment: Thanks! But this will only work with the method declared as instance method which is started by `-`. I can't get the methodSignature declared as class method which is started by `+`

Comment: That is not correct.  There are 2 different methods: `instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:` and `methodSignatureForSelector:`.  One does instance methods; one does class methods.

Comment: The `ADD` part is not correct, see the test codes from @Ben Flynn

Answer (score 4):

Here is additional detail about invoking class (and instance methods) via NSInvocation showing `methodForSignature:` and `instanceMethodForSignature:`

```
@interface SomeObject : NSObject
+ (void)instanceAndClass;
- (void)instanceAndClass;
+ (void)classOnly;
- (void)instanceOnly;
@end

@implementation SomeObject
+ (void)instanceAndClass { NSLog(@"Class version"); }
- (void)instanceAndClass { NSLog(@"Instance version"); }    
+ (void)classOnly { NSLog(@"Class only"); }
- (void)instanceOnly { NSLog(@"Instance only"); }
@end

@implementation Foo

- (void)invoke:(id)receiver signature:(NSMethodSignature *)signature selector:(SEL)selector {
    if (!signature) {
        NSLog(@"method signature is nil");
        return;
    }        
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
    invocation.selector = selector;
    invocation.target = receiver;
    [invocation invoke];
}

- (void)foo {
    NSMethodSignature *signature;
    SomeObject *someObject = [SomeObject new];

    signature = [someObject methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(instanceAndClass)];
    [self invoke:someObject signature:signature selector:@selector(instanceAndClass)];
    // 2015-07-10 11:01:10.227 FooBar[65312:3097866] Instance version
    [self invoke:[someObject class] signature:signature selector:@selector(instanceAndClass)];
    // 2015-07-10 11:01:10.227 FooBar[65312:3097866] Class version

    signature = [someObject methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(classOnly)];
    [self invoke:someObject signature:signature selector:@selector(classOnly)];
    // 2015-07-10 11:01:10.227 FooBar[65312:3097866] method signature is nil

    signature = [[someObject class] methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(classOnly)];
    [self invoke:[someObject class] signature:signature selector:@selector(classOnly)];
    // 2015-07-10 11:01:10.228 FooBar[65312:3097866] Class only

    signature = [someObject methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(instanceOnly)];
    [self invoke:someObject signature:signature selector:@selector(instanceOnly)];
    // 2015-07-10 11:01:10.228 FooBar[65312:3097866] Instance only

    signature = [[someObject class] methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(instanceOnly)];
    [self invoke:[someObject class] signature:signature selector:@selector(instanceOnly)];
    2015-07-10 11:01:10.228 FooBar[65312:3097866] method signature is nil

    signature = [[someObject class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(instanceOnly)];
    [self invoke:someObject signature:signature selector:@selector(instanceOnly)];
    // 2015-07-10 11:01:10.228 FooBar[65312:3097866] Instance only
}
```